# Is there a way to get bundler or gem to tell you where it got each gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

We use rvm, bundler, rails.  We have our own gems, and our own gem server.  We try to have all of our gems on our gem server, but we do also list rubygems.org at the top of our Gemfiles.  We sometimes get an HTTP error when bundling.  This is frustrating, especially when it happens on our circleci build after we merge a feature branch that passed it's tests.  Is there a way to get bundler or gem to say where it is getting each gem?  This would help in managing our gems.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does the shell script

```
array=(`gem list --no-versions`)
for gem in ${array[*]}
do
bundle show ${gem}
done
```

do the trick? It only shows installed gems though ...

Comment: I like that script, but I am talking about what gem server I get my gems from if I list more than one.  This lists local location of the installed gems after I get them.